# How to expect (jest) a function to be called with an object that needs processing before it can be matched

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm testing that a (constructor) function is called with a particular object, however the object itself has properties which themselves are JSON. This is because the third-party API which I am mocking expects this type of object, so I can't change it.

I want to test these JSON properties by converting them back to objects and using something like `expect.objectContaining`, because it is less brittle than trying to match the complete object, or worse still the JSON string.

I am testing an AWS Lambda SNS send function but I don't think that's entirely relevant, except to explain the syntax of my system under test:

```
export async function handler(event: any) {
    let sns = new SNSClient({ region: REGION });
    let myMessage = {}; // create my message
    let params = {
        Message: JSON.stringify(myMessage),
        TopicArn: 'my ARN'
    }

    const result = await sns.send(new PublishCommand(params));
    // some stuff
    return true;
}
```

My tests:

```
import { handler } from "./handler";
import { SNSClient, PublishCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sns";

const mockSnsSend = jest.fn();
mockSnsSend.mockResolvedValue({ MessageId: 1 });
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-sns', () => {
    return {
        SNSClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                send: mockSnsSend
            }
        }),
        PublishCommand: jest.fn().mockImplementation()
    }
});


beforeEach(() => {
    // Clear all instances and calls to constructor and all methods:
    mockSnsSend.mockClear();
    (SNSClient as any).mockClear();
    (PublishCommand as any).mockClear();
    expect.hasAssertions();
});


test('Calls PublishCommand with correct message payload', async () => {
    let results = await handler(sampleLoraThingMessage);

    expect(PublishCommand).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    // what to do here?
});
```

### What I've tried:

### expect a string

This is easy and passes, but it is not sufficient:

```
expect(PublishCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
    Message: expect.any(String)
}));
```

### extend expect

As per [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers) I've tried extending expect to parse the JSON and then run an `equals` test over it, but I found that this is only available to the `expect(a).hasJsonMatchingObject(b)` syntax, and I can't use it with `toHaveBeenCalledWith`.

```
expect.extend({
    hasJsonMatchingObject(received, propertyName: string, actual: object) {
        let parsed = JSON.parse(received[propertyName]);
        let pass = this.equals(parsed, actual, undefined, false);
        return {
            pass: pass,
            // todo: I haven't handled the .not() case here yet
            message: () => `property ${propertyName} must have JSON with certain properties:` +
                '\n\n' +
                `Expected: not ${this.utils.printExpected(actual)}\n` +
                `Received: ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
        };
    }
})

...
expect(PublishCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.hasJsonMatchingObject(...)); // expect has no property 'hasJsonMatchingObject'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the process of writing this, I found an answer, and since I think I've put a bit of effort into it and I couldn't find it documented well elsewhere so I'm going to post and answer...

### spy on argument

Jest gives you access to arguments passed to any mock implementation. So long as your function is mocked:

```
someFunc: jest.fn().mockImplementation()
```

`someFunc.mock.calls` gives access to parameters for each call to the function ([docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls)):

```
let arg = someFunc.mock.calls[0][0]; // first call, first argument
```

then it's as simple as using any existing code to extract the properties for my test. Because I've mocked a module, I have to cast it back to a jest.Mock to satisfy Typescript:

```
// first make sure Message is a string
expect(PublishCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
    Message: expect.any(String)
}));
// then test Message.Message is a json object with certain properties
let arg = (PublishCommand as jest.Mock).mock.calls[0][0]; // first call, first argument
let actual = JSON.parse(arg.Message);
expect(actual).toMatchObject({
    'prop1': 'expected value',
    'prop2': 'expected value'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to this is to [`expect.extend`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers):

Real-life example first, then quote below

```
  expect(sendMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
     expect.myCustomPathMatcher("/custom-path?query=*23*&size=200"),
     expect.any(Function), expect.any(Function), 0, true, true);
```

With the matcher

```
const requestMatchingPath = (request, path) =>
{
   if (typeof request === "function") request = request();

   const pass = request.path === path;
   let message = "all is well";
   if (!pass)
   {
      message = `expected ${request.path} to match ${path}`;
      console.error(message); // TODO: how to show message on failure?
   }
   return {
      message: () => message,
      pass,
   };
};

expect.extend({requestMatchingPath});
```

---

> You can use expect.extend to add your own matchers to Jest. For example, let's say that you're testing a number utility library and you're frequently asserting that numbers appear within particular ranges of other numbers. You could abstract that into a toBeWithinRange matcher:
>
> ```
> import {expect} from '@jest/globals';
>
> function toBeWithinRange(actual, floor, ceiling) {
>   if (
>     typeof actual !== 'number' ||
>     typeof floor !== 'number' ||
>     typeof ceiling !== 'number'
>   ) {
>     throw new Error('These must be of type number!');
>   }
>
>   const pass = actual >= floor && actual <= ceiling;
>   if (pass) {
>     return {
>       message: () =>
>         `expected ${this.utils.printReceived(
>           actual,
>         )} not to be within range ${this.utils.printExpected(
>           `${floor} - ${ceiling}`,
>         )}`,
>       pass: true,
>     };
>   } else {
>     return {
>       message: () =>
>         `expected ${this.utils.printReceived(
>           actual,
>         )} to be within range ${this.utils.printExpected(
>           `${floor} - ${ceiling}`,
>         )}`,
>       pass: false,
>     };
>   }
> }
>
> expect.extend({
>   toBeWithinRange,
> });
> ```

used e.g. in the following test:

> ```
> import {expect, test} from '@jest/globals';
> import '../toBeWithinRange';
>
> test('is within range', () => expect(100).toBeWithinRange(90, 110));
>
> test('is NOT within range', () => expect(101).not.toBeWithinRange(0, 100));
>
> test('asymmetric ranges', () => {
>   expect({apples: 6, bananas: 3}).toEqual({
>     apples: expect.toBeWithinRange(1, 10),
>     bananas: expect.not.toBeWithinRange(11, 20),
>   });
> });
> ```